# Default template argument deduction for copy initialization

Tags: c++, c++17, template-argument-deduction

C++17 has [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction). However, I was wondering whether it applies to statements like `auto x = X()` where `X` is a class template. Consider this code:

```
template <typename T = void>
struct X {};

int main() {       // all with -std=c++17
    X<> x0;        // compiles in both clang and gcc
    X x1;          // compiles in both clang and gcc
    auto x2 = X(); // compiles in clang but not gcc
    X<> x3 = X();  // compiles in clang but not gcc
}
```

Here is the [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/dkf3V4). So which compiler is right, and is this program valid C++17?

Comment: Those statements should all be well-formed. It's a gcc bug.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81486

Comment: @Barry Does this bug really come from the class template argument deduction feature? I figured it didn't since there was no deduction actually happening.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yeah, CTAD is what lets you write `X x;` instead of having to write `X<> x;`

Comment: @Barry Great. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in GCC.

Notice that if you replace the parenthesis with curly braces the code compiles:

```
auto x2 = X{}; // now compiles in clang and gcc
X<> x3 = X{}; // now compiles in clang and gcc
```

<strike>This is not class template argument deduction as there are no template arguments being deduced.</strike> Class template argument deduction should permit the elision of the template braces. The use of `()` or `{}` in this case should have no bearing on whether they are deduced.